How did the Briskers, or the Soloveitchiks, acquire the reputation for exactingness in quotation?
I recently came across a story about the Vilna Ga’on in Halachic Man (on p.30 in the 1984 English edition). I had various doubts about the authenticity of the story, and in the course of discussing my doubts with several people I kept hearing the assurance that the Briskers, or the Soloveitchiks, are very careful about such things and can be trusted to tell the story only because they have authenticated it.
How did the Briskers or the Soloveitchiks acquire this reputation for this sort of exactingness?

The Briskers tell their stories in excruciating detail, that exactly matches the way the previous generation told them. Allegedly

They probably obtained their reputation for precision because their Method emphasizes precisely defining concepts beforehand to better to understand difficulties in Gemara. They probably underwent flanderization and gained a reputation as sticklers and fact checkers overall.
